# How to filter nginx error log

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a public nginx webserver in ec2 that gets bombarded by garbage URLs.  Is there a way to configure nginx error log so that it wont log 'No such file or directory' and 'directory index of X forbidden' errors?

I don't want to change the loglevel to crit.

Comment: Is the issue that you want a log file you can watch that doesn't have this?  Or are you concerned about disk space due to the log size?

Comment: Both.  Having a webserver on a cloud with well known ip ranges I know I'm going to get sniffers. File not found is not valuable info for me, as I can get the info from analytics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`log_not_found off`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#log_not_found) disables logging "no such file/directory" messages. My advice is to set on per-location basis, for the typical locations these bad guys are sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off installing [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and configuring an suitable [set of jails](http://codelog.climens.net/2011/02/13/using-fail2ban-with-nginx-in-debian/) for the nginx logs. This way your firewall deals with the blocking and your nginx doesn't get to deal with them.